# How to get the previously used command in HP-UX reverse search

Tags: ksh, command-history

I'm using HP-UX OS and want to use previously typed command, as how I'm using in Linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for ease access in the HP-UX command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your not familiar with "vi" or "emacs" prompt commands the best would be to use the `fc` shell built-in command look at the "fc" help into the  `man sh-posix` manpage. Use the mouse to copy paste the commands.

The HP-UX shell is `/usr/bin/sh` the "POSIX shell" which command prompt is close to the korn shell, by default it is set to the **vi** command mode

"Esc" will put the prompt in "command mode", that mode is similar to the **vi** command mode.
Then you can hit:

- k to move backwards or j to move forward  in the history.
- i, a, A, cw or cW  will put the prompt back in edit mode (cw means change word).
- "/pattern" will search for the first command matching "pattern". If
  you type "n" (n means "next") it will look backwards to next
  occurrence of "pattern" into the history, "N" will looks into the other
  direction.

If you prefer the **emacs** mode like in bash,  use `set -o emacs` command.  Arrows keys should not works, use instead Ctrl commands :

- Ctrl-p  previous command
- Ctrl-n  next command
- Ctrl-f  cursor move forward
- Ctrl-b  cursor move backwards
- Ctrl-a  begin of line
- Ctrl-e  end of line
- Ctrl-r   Search for string in the history (another ctrl-r will go to the next occurence)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for the next "n" option in pattern search.

Answer (score 2):

For HP-UX you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and pressing again will cycle through the history.

To search through the history you can <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> `Search string`.